# Links on my webpage point to 127.0.0.1 domain instead of servers ip address

Tags: http, localhost, elgg

I am installng ELGG which is a social networking framework on top of xampp.  Everything works ok when it is run on the server e.g.

```
    http://127.0.0.1/.....
```

When I try to view the page from another computer on the network by entering

```
    http://(the servers ip address)....
```

The first page loads but all the links try to goto

```
    http://127.0.0.1/....
```

and it appears that it's trying to grab the assets from 127.0.0.1.

I looked alot online about this but I can't narrow it down to what is actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that the entry for your site in the elgg_sites_entity database table needs to be updated.  (that table name presumes you used "elgg_" as you database table prefix - set when you did your install)

See this page: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Duplicate_Installation 
Specifically this part: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Duplicate_Installation#Change_the_installation_path

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `site_entity` table's link and 2 entries in `datalists` table.

```
UPDATE `elgg_datalists` SET `value` = "/var/www/elgg_test/" WHERE `name` = "path";
UPDATE `elgg_datalists` SET `value` = "/var/data/elgg_test/" WHERE `name` = "dataroot";
UPDATE `elgg_sites_entity` SET `url` = "http://test.myelgg.org/";
```

Please see [here](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Duplicate_Installation#Change_the_installation_path)